# JavaScript not being called from Html

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a simple HTML 5 file, that creates a canvas, and is supposed to call a javascript file to generate and draw a table onto the said canvas:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Table Management</title>
        <script src="js/draw_table.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body onload="drawBoard();" style="background: lightblue;">
        <h1>Table Management</h1>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="420px" height="420px" style="background: #fff; magrin: 20px;"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var bw = 400;
var bh = 400;
var p = 10;
var cw = bw + (p * 2) + 1;
var ch = bh + (p * 2) + 1;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawBoard() {

    alert("Cheese");

    for (var x = 0; x <= bw; x += 40) {
        alert(x);
        context.moveTo(0.5 + x + p, p);
        context.lineTo(0.5 + x + p, bh + p);
    }

    for (var x = 0; x <= bh; x += 40) {
        context.moveTo(p, 0.5 + x + p);
        context.lineTo(bw + p, 0.5 + x + p);
    }

    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.stroke();
}
```

The problem is, that the table is not being drawn. In addition, i am planning to expand this into a table management system, where you can move cell content around by using drag and drop. Is this the best way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Your code is likely running before the DOM has finished loading, and so the reference to the canvas is no good. (Lesson: always check return values!) A common approach is to run "when loaded" code in response to `window.onload`, or to use jQuery's `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: If you want to move table elements around using a graphics canvas seems overkill. Why not just drag and drop `<td>` elaments?

Comment: Its an assignment. And they said we have to use canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dodgy example at http://jsfiddle.net/aKR2u/, as the javascript is called onLoad and event's don't seem to work.

The problem is you are trying to get the canvas before it is created, so canvas gets set to `null`. So you should move

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

to your `drawBoard()` function or something else that is called after the canvas has loaded. If you want to keep canvas and context global you could do:

```
...

var canvas;
var context;

function drawBoard() {

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ...
}
```

Comment: I did that. Could it be that its not showing because im testing it inside of eclipse?

Comment: @TastyLemons No idea :S. Try accessing it with your web browser or something.

Comment: So the way im calling it <body onload="drawBoard();" is fine?

Comment: @TastyLemons it seems to work on my browser (Chrome) on http://testnaman.neocities.org/quicktest4.html, though I think <body onload="drawBoard()" (without the semicolon) should be fine as well like it has been done here, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp.

Comment: Yeah it was eclipse :P

Answer (score 0):

Access these control in the function.

```
function drawBoard() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ....
}
```